# Where can I find a collection of Threat Models?

Tags: business-risk, risk-management, threat-modeling, risk-analysis

I found a very nice SSL Threat model [on this web page](https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_Threat_Model.png) and would like to find more on different topics.

How would I go about locating more images like these?  Is there an organisation or website I could go to?

Comment: Has this answered your question. Please let us know.

Comment: @BernieWhite - Yes this is great!  I hope people continue to add threat models to this list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SANS.org have a few really good resources. Including:

- http://www.sans.org/windows-security/2009/07/11/practical-risk-analysis-spreadsheet/
- http://software-security.sans.org/resources/paper/reading-room/threat-modeling-process-ensure-application-security
- http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/securecode/threat-modeling-process-ensure-application-security_1646

Also for web application try https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Threat_Risk_Modeling.

Answer (score 3):

If you like to get into the basics of Threat Models, then *[Threat Modelling](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6892)* from Microsoft Press is a nice book. Don't be put off by the introduction-page, it is an overall fine beginner read.

Answer (score 2):

MyAppSecurity's ThreatModeler uses a software centric approach to Threat Modeling.  It includes a feature to view an Attack Graph / Threat Pattern for individual software components.

[ThreatModeler Page](http://www.myappsecurity.com/threatmodeler/)